# Can't get Heroku to serve public index.html page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I've been trying to launch my project https://github.com/robdrosenberg/news-hunt on Heroku the last couple days and heroku won't serve my public/index.html page.

Here is the error I'm currently getting:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/")
```

This error has been brought up all over StackOverflow and I've tried as many of those solutions as I could.

For example, routing to the file directly through a welcome controller gives me an error as well

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create'
  post 'users' => 'users#create'
  namespace :api do
    get 'reddit' => 'posts#reddit'
    get 'producthunt' => 'posts#producthunt'
    get 'medium' => 'posts#medium'
    get 'hackernews' => 'posts#hackernews'
    get 'githubtrending' => 'posts#githubtrending'
    get 'all' => 'posts#all'
    get 'bookmarks' => 'bookmarks#index'
    post 'bookmarks' => 'bookmarks#create'
    delete 'bookmarks' => 'bookmarks#destroy'
  end
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

**Controller**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render file: Rails.root.join('public','index.html')
  end
end
```

**Error**

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template public/index.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: app/app/views
```

Changing `config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?` to = true hasn't made a difference.

I've tried using redirects which result in the app crashing from too many redirects.

What I find odd is when I try to render the file directly it searches in the app/views folder. Everything works fine locally, so it has to be something with the production environment and Heroku.

I'm using Rails in API mode and using Vue through CDN in my index.html file.

I deployed a different project the same way and had no issues. You can find that codebase here: https://github.com/robdrosenberg/commitment-ledger.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: By default Rails will look in the app views directory.  Specifically it will look for a folder called `welcome`, so `app/views/welcome` that has a file called `index.html.erb` , the end result being `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` is what Rails expects.  if you look at the route it will make sense `root 'welcome#index'`, so `welcome` is the folder inside the views directory, and `index.html.erb` is the file it will look for.

Comment: Have you tried `/index`?

Comment: @RockwellRice Wouldn't root 'welcome#index' route to the index method in my welcome controller? I have that pointing to a file it should render.

Comment: @SimonBrazell where should I try putting /index? Not sure what you mean sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t actually have a `public/index.html` page in that repo, but rather a `public/Index.html` (note the case of the ‘i’ and ‘I’). This won’t make much difference if you’re developing on Windows or Mac, but on Linux (which is used on Heroku) they will be treated as different files.

Rename the file to `index.html` (use `git mv` and don’t forget to commit) and it should work.

Comment: So this was the issue. I checked for it but I did not use git mv. I officially feel dumb but I’m still learning. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `config/routes.rb` file:

`get '', to: redirect('/Index.html')`

That way the requests to the application root will redirect to the index file in the public folder.

As mentioned below you have named the file with a capital ‘I’, you will need to use the same case when referencing it in the redirect above, as updated.

Comment: This is the error I get when trying your solution. `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/index.html"):` the index.html file does exist in the public file when I check for it in heroku bash.

Comment: That’s pretty strange, to be honest I only tried it with the files already present in the public folder in my local environment e.g. 404.html etc. maybe try renaming the file to something other than index?

Comment: Updated to include the correct file name, please try again with the updated redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to redirect to public/index? Of course, I don't know your application, so this may not be helpful. Have you considered moving your index.html file to the views/welcome directory? This is the default location that the welcome#index method will render a file from.

Comment: I don't want to redirect to that file, but I've tried it based on other peoples solutions throughout Stack Overflow. I haven't tried moving my index.html file to a views folder. Does it need to be an index.html.erb file for it to work in there?

Comment: I tried moving the index file to the welcome views folder and routing to it. I got this error:

`Missing template Users/robertrosenberg/news-hunt/views/welcome/index.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/robertrosenberg/news-hunt/app/views" * "/Users/robertrosenberg/news-hunt" * "/"`

Comment: It sounds like @matt may have found the problem with both of these errors in that filenames are case-sensitive in Linux.